# More "formal" description for an experiment

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random, word-problem

I have an experiment with $n$ elements. Each one have a different probability $p_i \in [0,1]$ of being chosen (all the probabilities can sum more than 1). Finally, $m$ of these $n$ elements are chosen based on their probability.

**Question:** I would like give a more formal description of this experiment, also using some "technical" words in the field of statistics & probability. Is that possible?

**Explanation of the process:** To do this experiment, I'm employing the `sample` function in R, using its `prob`argument, which indicates the weight of each element to be chosen. I don't know exactly how it works. I've only read that "probabilities are applied sequentially, that is the probability of choosing the next item is proportional to the weights amongst the remaining items.

I'm not sure of the exact algorithm used in `sample`, but I imagine that the process of the `sample`function using weights is something similar to this:

- Elements are picked one by one, randomly, until  elements are chosen.
- I pick an element and check if it finally chosen based on its probability.
- If it is chosen, it is removed from the list of  elements, avoiding it is chosen again.
- If not, I pick another random element and repeat the process.

Comment: (1) Is $m$ fixed? (2) As a "problem", what are we supposed to solve?

Comment: (1) Yes, $n$, $m$ and the probability of each element are known. (2) It is not a problem (I have already fixed the question). It is the description of an experiment to select some individuals from a population based on these probabilities.

Comment: If you choose probabilistically which element you pick with probability $p_i$, how can you know beforehand the exact number of picks $m$ ? Do you know $m$ only because you performed the experiment or is it a constraint that you must pick exactly $m$ elements ?

Comment: $m$ is a constraint of the experiment. I need to choose $m$ elements, but this choice is based on those probabilities $p_i$.

Comment: @dreamco9 You should edit the post to include the exact process you used to choose these elements, the mathematical description can be wildly different. Ex: did you start picking element one by one stopping once you reached $m$, if so was it in a deterministic order or a random one? Or maybe starting from the probabilities $p_i$ you constructed a probability measure on the subset of $n$ with size $m$ and then use this to pick the elements. Without further clarification I don’t think we can be of much help

Comment: I did it, although I don't have too much information on the operation of the `sample`function in R.

Answer (score 2):

This is successive sampling (by default without replacement) with weights; the weights can add up to $1$ but do not need to; any positive numbers will work.  Without replacement it is related to the ideas behind the [Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution). `?sample` will show you [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html)

As an illustration, consider `sample(c("A","B","C"),size=2,prob=c(2,1,3))` which will give a weighted sample of two of $A,B,C$ using the relative weights $2,1,3$:

- The first item may be $A$ with probability $\frac{2}{2+1+3}=\frac13$

  - The second item may then be $B$ with conditional probability $\frac{1}{1+3}=\frac14$, making the joint probability of $(A,B)$ $\frac1{12}$
  - The second item may then be $C$ with conditional probability $\frac{3}{1+3}=\frac34$, making the joint probability of $(A,C)$ $\frac1{4}$
- The first item may be $B$ with probability $\frac{1}{2+1+3}=\frac16$

  - The second item may then be $A$ with conditional probability $\frac{2}{2+3}=\frac25$, making the joint probability of $(B,A)$ $\frac1{15}$
  - The second item may then be $C$ with conditional probability $\frac{3}{2+3}=\frac35$, making the joint probability of $(B,C)$ $\frac1{10}$
- The first item may be $C$ with probability $\frac{3}{2+1+3}=\frac12$

  - The second item may then be $A$ with conditional probability $\frac{2}{2+1}=\frac23$, making the joint probability of $(C,A)$ $\frac1{3}$
  - The second item may then be $B$ with conditional probability $\frac{1}{2+1}=\frac13$, making the joint probability of $(C,B)$ $\frac1{6}$

If you are not interested in the outcome of the order then the joint probabilities (adding up to $1$) are:

- the probability of $\{A,B\}$ being the sample is $\frac1{12}+\frac{1}{15}=\frac3{20}$
- the probability of $\{A,C\}$ being  the sample is $\frac1{4}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac7{12}$
- the probability of $\{B,C\}$ being  the sample is $\frac1{10}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac4{15}$

The probability of individual items being sampled (adding up to $2$ since two items are sampled) are:

- For $A$: $\frac3{20}+\frac7{12}=\frac{11}{15}\approx 0.733$
- For $B$: $\frac3{20}+\frac4{15}=\frac{5}{12}\approx 0.417$
- For $C$: $\frac7{12}+\frac4{15}=\frac{17}{20}=0.85$

Simulation confirms this interpretation, for example with

```
set.seed(2022)
sims <- replicate(10000,sample(c("A","B","C"),size=2,prob=c(2,1,3)))
table(sims)
# sims
#   A    B    C 
# 7345 4171 8484
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a very complete example. I understand now how `sample` with weights works. My doubt is if there is any general way to describe this type of experiment using a mathematical/probabilisitic language (see the original question).